# How do you uninstall a package that you manually cloned from git

Tags: linux, rhel, configuration, tmux

I want to uninstall tmux on my machine. My tmux version is:

```
tmux next-3.4
```

and `which tmux` gives me:

```
/usr/local/bin/tmux
```

I tried to uninstall it with `sudo yum remove tmux`, and I get:

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
No match for argument: tmux
No packages marked for removal.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

My machine info is as follows:

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.6 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.6"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.6 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://access.redhat.com/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.6
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6"
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't install a tmux package, you compiled and installed tmux yourself - so the package management tools, e.g. `yum`, know nothing about your self-installed version of tmux.

In short: you installed it manually, you'll have to uninstall it manually.

Some possibilities that might make this easier:

- Some programs come with both an `install` and and `uninstall` target in their Makefile.  I don't know if `tmux` does this, but it's worth checking.  Either run `make uninstall` or examine tmux's Makefile to see if it has that target. Note that `uninstall` makefile targets aren't always reliable and generally aren't tested anywhere near as well as `build` or `install` targets.  caveat emptor. YMMV. Good luck!
- Run `make -n install` and make note of all files which would be installed.  Then delete them manually.  Hint: it would help to redirect `make -n`'s output to a file, especially if there's a lot of output.

  BTW, in case it's not obvious,`make`'s `-n` option is a dry-run - from `man make`:

  > `-n`, `--just-print`, `--dry-run`, `--recon`
  >
  > Print the commands that would be executed, but do not execute them
  > (except in certain circumstances).

---

##### Recommendations for the future:

Either stick to packaged software or use programs like [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) or [CheckInstall](http://checkinstall.izto.org) when compiling and installing software.  They provide some (but not all) of the useful functionality of packages, and make it easier to upgrade and/or uninstall self-compiled software.

Note that 99+% of the time, there's little or no benefit to compiling software yourself.  "It's shinier and newer" and "it has a bigger version number" are almost never good enough reasons.   Especially so if you don't know how to uninstall a program that you've self-compiled, or the difference between packaged and self-compiled software.

If there's a specific new feature that you absolutely must have, or a bug that affects you and you KNOW for a fact that it's fixed in the latest upstream version AND you can't wait a few days or weeks for the package to be updated then it *might* be worth the hassle...but even then it usually isn't, you're just trading one problem (a bug, or lack of a feature) for another (unpackaged software).  It's almost always better to just wait.

Or, rather than just download the source and run `make install`, learn enough about your distro's packaging system to build your own package of the latest version.  Quite often this can be as simple as downloading the **package** source files and applying upstream patches to it and then re-building the package, or porting the packaging changes (e.g. debian/ directory on debian/ubuntu/etc, or spec file etc on RPM-based distros) to the newest upstream source.

Comment: There's a good chance that all the stuff is under /usr/local, which *only* has stuff you installed this way and nothing else, so you can just look for that stuff and delete it.